# How to link existing shapes in excel with a straight line using VBA dynamically

Tags: excel, vba

i've 4 rounded rectangular shapes in "sheet1" of a workbook, now i want to link them with their shape names. The shape names will be in column A of another sheet, the names in the column and the names in the text frame of shape will be same, so i need to link them using VBA code, i am a beginner in VBA, i've tried some code but stuck in between, can anyone help me out to solve my problem.

```
Sub ConnectingShapes()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim txBox As Shape
Dim sTemp As String
On Error Resume Next
Set myDocument = Worksheets(1)
Set s = myDocument.Shapes
i = 2
For Each shp In s.Shapes
'With myDocument.Shapes.AddLine(10, 10, 250, 250).Line
    '.DashStyle = msoLineDashDotDot
    '.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(50, 0, 128)
'End With
'sTemp = shp.Name
txBox = shp.Name
If shp.Name = sTemp Then
Set c = s.AddConnector(msoConnectorCurve, 0, 0, 100, 100)
With c.ConnectorFormat
    .BeginConnect ConnectedShape:=txBox, ConnectionSite:=1
    .EndConnect ConnectedShape:=Cells(i , 9), ConnectionSite:=1
     c.RerouteConnections
End With
i = i + 2
Else
MsgBox ("Nothing Found")
End If`enter code here`
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a great update to your first [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891512/how-to-link-two-shapes-with-the-shape-names-using-excel-vba). Really embraces the spirit of SO, and giving things a try before asking. You may want to delete your other question so others searching for this issue are more easily directed here.

Answer (score 3):

This may be a good starting point.  You can copy this in a module; all info are in Sheet1:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ConnectingShapes()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = WS.Range("a" & WS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim Shp1 As Shape, Shp2 As Shape, Conn As Shape
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rowOffSet As Long: rowOffSet = 1
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        Set Shp1 = GetTxtBoxShapeByContent(WS.Cells(i, 1).Value, WS)
        If i = lastRow Then 'To check if we have to come back to beginning
            rowOffSet = -lastRow + 1
        End If
        Set Shp2 = GetTxtBoxShapeByContent(WS.Cells(i, 1).Offset(rowOffSet, 0).Value, WS)

        Set Conn = WS.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, 0, 100, 0, 100)
        With Conn.ConnectorFormat
            .BeginConnect Shp1, 1
            .EndConnect Shp2, 1
        End With
        Conn.RerouteConnections
        Set Conn = Nothing
    Next i
End Sub

'Function that gets the wanted txtbox by its content
Function GetTxtBoxShapeByContent(iTxtBoxVal As String, WS As Worksheet) As Shape
    Dim Shp As Shape
    For Each Shp In WS.Shapes
        If Shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text = iTxtBoxVal Then
            Set GetTxtBoxShapeByContent = Shp
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next Shp
End Function
```

Before running the macro:
[image]

Result:
[image]

Comment: @user3155012 No problem, glad I could help.  Also, if you consider this as the answer to your question, you could accept it as answer by clicking the check mark just below the down arrow.  Thanks.

Comment: is there anyway can i add extra points in there for example we have four points in every shape, can i insert 5th point.. is it possible @simpLEMAn

Comment: @user3713336; you can put as many as you want.  Just be sure to add the value in column "A".

Comment: @simpLEMAn   I am trying to add a point. Can you help me out, i don't understand what is column "A" have to do with it. Here is my question...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39875934/how-can-i-add-points-or-nodes-to-a-shape-in-vba?noredirect=1#comment67250404_39875934

Comment: @user3713336; my code posted in the answer above connects all the textboxes using their content (A, B, C, D) in the order they are listed in column "A".