# How can i add points or nodes to a shape in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to add points or nodes to a shape, so instead of having 4 points, I can h[image]ave more

Here is my code adding shapes

```
Set shap2 = w.Shapes.AddShape(1, 330, 55, 100, 40)
shap2.Nodes.Insert , 6, msoEditingAuto, 1, 1
```

I am getting an error when I am trying to add Nodes... Any idea?

Comment: I get an "argument not optional" error when I try the above code, so I think you'll need to specify the index of the new Node. Try `shap2.Nodes.Insert shap2.Nodes.Count, msoSegmentLine, msoEditingAuto, 1, 1`; this will insert a new Node after the last Node in the Shape.

Comment: @Socii This code insert a Line instead of a point, i want a insert a point not line, Ever shape has only 4 points, which is 1,2,3,4, i want to insert 5.

Comment: My bad... use `msoSegmentCurve` instead of `msoSegmentLine`. And if you already know how many points you have you can specify point 5 in your line of code: `shap2.Nodes.Insert 5, msoSegmentCurve, msoEditingAuto, 1, 1` should work.

Comment: @Socii    Is it possible to insert points without adding msoSegmentLine or Curve... I am adding shape then want to add points for the connection.. something like this ...  Set conn = w.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, 1, 1, 1, 1)
             conn.ConnectorFormat.BeginConnect shap1, 4
             conn.ConnectorFormat.EndConnect shap2, 2

Comment: Not that I know of, although I haven't done much VBA programming with shapes so I may be wrong. If you're aiming to add a connector between two shapes using the shortest path however, you can use the `RerouteConnections` method to adjust the connector. This will eliminate the need to add any extra points to the shape. `RerouteConnections` method is at [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840394.aspx), and this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022636/how-to-link-existing-shapes-in-excel-with-a-straight-line-using-vba-dynamically) may be useful.